# Perlin noise generator isn't working, doesn't look smooth

Tags: python, noise, perlin-noise, noise-generator

I watched some tutorials and tried to create a Perlin noise generator in python.
It takes in a tuple for the number of vectors in the x and y directions and a scale for the distance in pixels between the arrays, then calculates the dot product between each pixel and each of the 4 arrays surrounding it, It then interpolates them bilinearly to get the pixel's value.

here's the code:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

scale = 16
size = np.array([8, 8])
vectors = []

for i in range(size[0]):
    for j in range(size[1]):
        rand = np.random.rand() * 2 * np.pi
        vectors.append(np.array([np.cos(rand), np.sin(rand)]))

interpolated_map = np.zeros(size * scale)

def interpolate(x1, x2, w):
    t = (w % scale) / scale
    return (x2 - x1) * t + x1

def dot_product(a, b):
    return a[0] * b[0] + a[1] * b[1]

for i in range(size[1] * scale):
    for j in range(size[0] * scale):
        dot_products = []
        for m in range(4):
            corner_vector_x = round(i / scale) + (m % 2)
            corner_vector_y = round(j / scale) + int(m / 2)
            x = i - corner_vector_x * scale
            y = j - corner_vector_y * scale
            if corner_vector_x >= size[0]:
                corner_vector_x = 0
            if corner_vector_y >= size[1]:
                corner_vector_y = 0
            corner_vector = vectors[corner_vector_x + corner_vector_y * (size[0])]
            distance_vector = np.array([x, y])
            dot_products.append(dot_product(corner_vector, distance_vector))
        x1 = interpolate(dot_products[0], dot_products[1], i)
        x2 = interpolate(dot_products[2], dot_products[3], i)
        interpolated_map[i][j] = (interpolate(x1, x2, j) / 2 + 1) * 255

img = Image.fromarray(interpolated_map)

img.show()
```

I'm getting this image:
[image]

but I should be getting this:
[image]

I don't know what's going wrong, I've tried watching multiple different tutorials, reading a bunch of different articles, but the result is always the same.

Comment: Could you maybe link a bunch of different articles and multiple tutorials which are relevant?

Comment: To me this looks like an issue with truncating or rounding. Are all your `round()`s necessary? And the `int()`? I suggest finding some code which does work, then comparing it to yours and see where there are any differences.

Comment: The round() and int() are for getting the index in the array of vectors, to pick the correct one for each corner. They aren't part of the interpolation.

Comment: Most of the implementations I've seen of Perlin noise don't use scaling.  The corners are all integer coordinates, and the scaling is done when the image is output.  I'm wondering if there is some problem there.

Comment: an article and tutorial I followed to learn how to make perlin noise: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MJ3bvCkHJtE&t=954s https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perlin_noise